# Auto share git projects has encountered a problem

Tags: eclipse, egit

I added a spring tools 4 plugin in eclipse. However after restarting eclipse, it continuously builds the workspace with the following error:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
> Receiver class org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator$EclipseSystemReader does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.eclipse.jgit.lib.StoredConfig getUserConfig()' of abstract class org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.

Another error which is seen is:

> An internal error occurred during: "Auto share git projects".
> Receiver class org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator$EclipseSystemReader does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.eclipse.jgit.lib.StoredConfig getUserConfig()' of abstract class org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.

This however does not occur if I close all projects. I think it has something to do with `egit` and I am trying to turn it off but when I right click project and hover over the team options it shows nothing.

EDIT:
I think the reason for this error was, while installing the spring tools 4 plugin I initially quit eclipse abruptly without seeing the installation progress which might have broken things. When I opened eclipse the plugin was not installed so I again installed and after a restart it started showing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error was annoying so as a last resort I uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse and it fixed the issue. Also I am able to see team options now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of weird problem. We cannot blame GIT nor IDE's (eclipse or spring tool suite).

Best possible way to come out of this hiccup is to do a fresh git clone of the project into a new folder. Then create a new workspace and IMPORT the project from the IDE into the newly created workspace.